# how to create multiples of same form for user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, forms

I have a form in HTML that has a form object from my django ModelForms. I want to allow the user to dynamically add or remove copies of the same form if they choose. A similar example(the **online demo**) would be this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/

I am just not sure how to get started as I have little experience with JavaScript. Any input would be appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌

<form id="blockForm" class="original" action="{% url 'inventory:requests' inventory.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}   
<a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a>

<div class="requestForm">
    <div class="container">
        <ul><li><input {{form.as_table}} /></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Blocks" id="submitButton">
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function dupeForm() {
    var reqs = document.getElementsByClassName('requestForm'),
        btn = document.getElementById('submitButton'),
        len = reqs.length,
        lastReq = reqs[len - 1],
        newReq = lastReq.cloneNode(true),
        txtBxs = newReq.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    // I am unsure what this for loop does -quanuw
    for (var i = 0; i < txtBxs.length; i++) {
        txtBxs[i].setAttribute('name', 'txt' + len);
        txtBxs[i].setAttribute('id', 'txt' + len);
        txtBxs[i].value = 'More Text';
    }

    lastReq.parentNode.insertBefore(newReq, btn);
}

var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
var insertLink = document.getElementById('insert-more');

insertLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault();    dupeForm(); }, false);
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

</script>
```

Here is my modelform:

```
    class Block(models.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Request Blocks"

inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, null=True)
block_status = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='STATUS')
block_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='BLOCKNAME')
block_derivatives = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='DERIVATIVES')
block_subsystems = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='SUBSYSTEMS')
owners = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='OWNERS')


def __str__(self):              
    return self.block_name

def block_owners(self):
    return str(self.owners)
```

Comment: What about form id? HTML have unique id for elements

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You want to create copy of form right? Now in the form element there is an id blockForm. If you create a copy of form, the id on new form will be blockForm which should not be the case.

Comment: So should I remove the id?

Comment: Yes or you need to update your script so that it updates id as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

You can recreate the form object using JavaScript.  Then each time you need to add a form, you just rerun the JavaScript function.

Alternatively, you can create the form using regular HTML and assign it 'hidden' and the class 'original'.  Then each time you want to add a row, you run the following:

```
function(){
    var newForm = $('form#blockForm.original').clone().removeClass('original');
    newForm.appendTo($('div.container')).show();
}
```

To run this function, you might wrap it in a .click() event attached to the "Add Row" button.  Don't use `<a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a>`.  Instead, I prefer to go with the following:

HTML:

```
<span id="insert-more">Add New Row</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('span#insert-more').click(function(){
    var newForm = $('form#blockForm.original').clone().removeClass('original');
    newForm.appendTo($('div.container')).show();
});
```

And naturally, you need something to activate this javascript after the span has loaded.  I use `$(document).ready(function(){//This is where most of my JavaScript file goes.});`

---EDIT---

Okay, I suppose I wasn't very clear up at the top.  I was suggesting that you use a sort of master form that's hidden from view, with the class being 'original'.  Then when you copy this, the code I wrote removes that class, but only from the copy.  This is so that you do not copy any of the copies.  But you do need to put the class 'original' in the original form that you want to copy!  You also want to do away with most of the ids in the form, or simply don't use them at all.  I prefer to use classes for this, and then anything I do with the form is usually stated as follows.

```
$('button.formSubmit').click(function(){
    var $thisForm = $(this).parent().parent();
    //multiple parent functions may be chained together, depending on how far down the button is nested.
    //examples of use:
    $thisForm.children('input.blah1').doSomething();
    var inp2 = $thisForm.children('input.blah2');
    //Really, you can do anything at this point.
});
```

As for giving the forms unique ids, it is unnecessary so long as you have a way to figure out what belongs to which form, which is simple with the functionality of `$(this)` which identifies what thing was clicked on and works based off that.  Also, if you actually use the standard 'submit form' functionality, you don't have to worry about `$(this)` because it submits the form in which the button was clicked, regardless of id or class.  You only need to worry about ids when you're going to put something outside of a form that relates to something inside a particular form.  But since you're making duplicate forms, you wouldn't want to do that anyways.

Comment: So I put both parts of your javascript example into my js file, but add new is not working. Should I edit your code somehow to fit my requirements?

Comment: If you used the `$("span#insert-more")`, did you also change `<a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a>` to `<span id="insert-more">Add New Row</span>`?  If you really want to keep the link tag, you should instead use `$("a#insert-more")`.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Ok, so i changed the link tag to span, but how would i add a button or click event functionality to the add new row? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I'm not sure where your code is getting caught up at.  Do you know how to use the console, if so, paste the selector `$('span#insert-more')` in there to check to make sure you're selecting the right item.  If that's all good, click on the span and see if anything happens.  If nothing happens, the code I gave you may not have run because the span had not yet loaded.  If that's the case, you need to make sure it runs after the span loads by placing the entire `$(...).click(...)` code I gave you in the `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.

Comment: I just edited the question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Did you assign the original form the attribute hidden and the class 'original'?

Comment: Just added class original and hidden attribute to the form above. Could you show an example of this working on jsfiddle? I am just very confused right now on how to do this. thanks!

Comment: Ugh.... jsfiddle is soooo finicky.  I have to close all html tags and the console doesn't work.  Anywho... https://jsfiddle.net/d8yja91s/  Sorry for the delay; I was talking with my Aunt.  I have no idea what that other stuff you were putting in the middle of the form was about.  And yes, you do need to modify it to your needs.  You always need to modify it to your needs.  Every time you change a class or id or element type, you need to change the associated javascript/jquery.

Comment: No problem. Hmm, how do i just make copies of the fields. I Don't want a "Request Blocks" button for every new entry. I only need one Request button. Is that doable?

Comment: Yeah.  You just take the Request button out of the original form html element and put it above that element or below the container for the form elements.  I honestly had no idea what stuff you wanted in the repeating forms and what stuff you wanted left out.  Again, it's just an example.  And in the world of JavaScript, just about anything is doable.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker for you which clones your html form.

```
$(function(){
  $("#insert-more").click(function(){
    var form = $("#blockForm").clone();
    $(".container").append(form);
  });
});
```

"http://plnkr.co/edit/jAyl2EkSkMUPWQa4gwRg?p=preview

Comment: Ok, i removed the form id and also one of the divs since it seemed redundant.

Comment: Great. Did you checked my code? Will it work for you?

Comment: Just wondering, how will your script work if i deleted my form id? You use the selector "#blockForm".

Comment: I have updated the plunker for your review. Now it does not need form id

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but it's still not working. You think I have to allow my document to get ready first? Then call the function?

Comment: Yes. That is must because otherwise it will behave absurdly.

Comment: i put the ready event in the script, but it still isn't working. $(document).ready(function () {// Add your javascript here
  $("#insert-more").click(function(){
    var form = $($("form")[0]).clone();
    $(".container").append(form);
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to clone the form or just individual rows inside a single form? If it's really the latter, you can use a function to duplicate the fieldsets within your form and update the input field names to match.

```
function dupeForm() {
    var reqs = document.getElementsByClassName('requestForm'),
        btn = document.getElementById('submitButton'),
        len = reqs.length,
        lastReq = reqs[len - 1],
        newReq = lastReq.cloneNode(true),
        txtBxs = newReq.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < txtBxs.length; i++) {
        txtBxs[i].setAttribute('name', 'txt' + len);
        txtBxs[i].setAttribute('id', 'txt' + len);
        txtBxs[i].value = 'More Text';
    }

    lastReq.parentNode.insertBefore(newReq, btn);
}
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vp84oodt/

Comment: The form only has one row of fields, so does it make a difference if I want to clone the form or just the individual rows?

Comment: If you clone the whole form, you have to manage all the elements within that form for duplicate IDs and names. Also, I think an individual form's submit button will only submit the form it belongs to, not all the forms and all the forms names would be the same which might play havoc with wherever all that data is going.

Comment: Ok, so i need the form to be dynamic in the sense that the user can make multiple orders at once in the same submission, but each order should still have a unique id or pk in the database and should not be tied together. Will cloning be the right choice for this?

Comment: Sure, you just have to do house-cleaning on each field you clone to make sure the names and IDs don't duplicate. If you look at my example function and fiddle, that's exactly what I do, just on a simplified basis.

Comment: Hi, i updated the html and javascript code. I think there is a problem when i try to use the {{form.as_table}} instead of a normal input tag in the html. Could you please guide me in the right direction? I did try to nest the {{form.as_table}} in an input tag just like in your html example, but it failed.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of it?

Comment: I got it to work. Except when i hit submit, only the last clone of the form gets submitted into my database. If I have forms 1, 2, and 3 where 3 is the latest form only form 3 gets submitted. Do you know why that is? Is it because the submit button only works for one form?

Comment: Yes, this is why I suggested having a single form and cloning portions of the form within it.

Comment: So right now your script is cloning the entire form as a whole each time i click add new row?

Comment: No, just the `requestForm` element. Look at the code block and the fiddle-- I grab all the elements with the `requestForm` classname, clone the last one, and then append it after it (before the button).

Comment: Hi Tod, can you explain what the for loop does? I am assuming it creates unique id's for each field in a form. Is there to out put the names/ids of the fields to check for uniqueness? Also, why prevent the default action of submit? Here is my the: http://jsfiddle.net/vp84oodt/6/

Comment: I prevent the submit just for the fiddle so the page doesn't try to reload. For uniqueness, I just iterate through the fields and number the new set one higher than the last existing-- this assumes a simple numbering/naming system. I'm not super familiar with django-- have you checked out their form page? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: when you're looping it looks like you're adding 'txt' + len. Doesn't len always stay the same since it's the length of reqs? I am just so stuck as to why the submission only works for the last form created.

Comment: In the case of my fiddle, there's only one field. The loop only runs if you add a row so it just updates the new row, using len to figure out what number it is. So given a form with `row0`, `row1`, `row2`, the len would be 3. A new row would therefore be given the `ID` of `row3`, the prefix, `row`, and then the len, `3`.

Comment: Makes sense. Although I just checked to see if the form.field.name updates when I add a new row and it does not update. I am using the template {{form.block_name.name}} where block_name is a field in my form. Unless the loops is actually updated the name of a form and not its fields.

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with the Django elements of this so you'll have to probably do some research on how they work to see if they require anything special.

Comment: They're not special. The name attribute for the field block_name would just be set as name="block_name".